# GSAP onComplete fires immediately in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, gsap

I'm using Nuxt and I couldn't figure out why my onComplete call was firing immediately rather than waiting for the animation to complete:

I started with this code for calling my method from onComplete, because that's how you call methods in Nuxt:

```
this.gsapTimeline = this.gsap
        .timeline({
          paused: true,
          onComplete: this.callShowTimelineFunction(),
        })
        .to("#someID", {
          opacity: 1,
          duration: 2,
        });
```

But that syntax will cause the "callShowTimelineFunction" to fire immediately. Remove the brackets "()" from the method call and...in this case...the method won't be fired until the entire animation completes...like this:

```
this.gsapTimeline = this.gsap
        .timeline({
          paused: true,
          onComplete: this.callShowTimelineFunction,
        })
        .to("#someID", {
          opacity: 1,
          duration: 2,
        });
```

I just happened to find [this post](https://gsap.com/community/forums/topic/32833-is-there-a-method-that-can-run-a-function-after-gsapto/?do=findComment&comment=164392) on GSAP. As elegantseagulls explains:

> To note you'll want to do onComplete: functionName, not onComplete:
> functionName() as this will run the function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: if your onComplete is firing immediately you may be using the wrong syntax to call your Nuxt method.

To properly call your method from the onComplete in a GSAP timeline, you'll want to do onComplete: functionName, not onComplete: functionName() as this will run the function immediately.